# Xamarin, how get certificate number in the android device?

Tags: android, xamarin, certificate, ssl-certificate

I use xamarin.
How I can get certificate number of my ssl-certificate file in the android device?

Comment: How would you do it if you were using Android Studio?

Comment: No, I used VS2015 with Xamarin Studio

Comment: I understand that you are using VS/Xamarin. A common way to discover how you would do something in Xamarin is to first find out how to do it in Android Studio, then find the equivalent in Xamarin.